# The covariance function of a stochastic process is positive semidefinite

Tags: time-series, self-study, stochastic-processes

Let $\{X_t, t \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ a real-valued stochastic process and $\gamma : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ the autocovariance function. I would like to show it is a positive semidefinite function. Is showing this equivalent to showing that the covariance matrix of a given random vector of the stochastic process is positive semidefinite?

Comment: This question sounds like it is based on homework or some independent self study. If so, please attach the `self-study` tag to this question and read the information in this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) to see how we try to provide help for such questions.

Comment: Is $T$ a discrete set (e.g. the integers) or a continuous set (e.g. the real line)?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Updated to restrict it to $\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the definition of positive semidefininteness directly:
Let $t_1, t_2, \cdots, t_k \subset \mathbb{R}$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma(t_i, t_j)
\end{bmatrix}_{1\leq i, j \leq k}
$$
is the variance-covariance matrix of $X_{t_1}, \cdots, X_{t_k}$, which must be positive semidefininte.

(It does not matter whether the process is indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.)